# Type check with list of types

Tags: c++

Is it possible to pass multiple derived types to `std::is_same_v`?
I was trying to implement some function which takes as first argument an object with type `T` and a list of types; The solution does not work; Is there a way to avoid a verbose line like `std::is_same_v<T, int> || std::is_same_v<T, float> || ...`?

```
template<typename T, typename ... Types>
constexpr bool isinstance(
    const T& object
) {
    for (auto& type : types)
        if std::is_same_v<type, T>
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `return (std::is_same_v<T, Types> || ...);`. This is called a *fold expression*.

Comment: With this hint I actually found what I was looking for, thanks! I am gonna mark this as duplicate.